# Redirecting standard output to new file adds strange character to end of filename in cygwin

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, sh

I'm having trouble with a shell script in Cygwin. The specific command that's causing the problem is this:

```
sed -e "s/6.0.[0123456789]\{1,\}/6.0.${REV}/g" "path/to/file/config.xml" > "path/to/file/config.xml.tmp"
```

The problem is that the file is being created with a strange character at the end, so instead of being named config.xml.tmp, it's named "config.xml.tmp". From the "ls" command and from the windows command prompt, it looks like "config.xml.tmp?"

If I run the sed command just from the shell, the file named correctly, and the script works fine in Linux.

Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your script file doesn't have UNIX line endings.  The `\r` character in the windows line ending is what's getting added to the end of your filename.  You can check with `od` or `hexdump` to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I've got what is likely the identical problem, but I'm invoking cygwin 1.7.6-1's sh.exe from make on Windows. I don't have this problem when using earlier versions of cygwin and I can't change the line-endings of this makefile, any suggestions for my situation?

Comment: Why can't you change the line endings?  Cygwin's bash has a shell option to ignore them, maybe you can try that.